# element.clientHeight is triggered by javascript before image is loaded

Tags: javascript, html

On my website, the margin-top of one element is dependent on the height of an image.

1. I had used image.clientHeight for this purpose. When I load the page from the url, it works.  But, on refreshing the page, the margin-top is 0. After reading, I found out that this was happening because the js script was being loaded before the page was loaded (Please correct me if my understanding is flawed).
2. So, I put the js script from the separate file at the end of the html's body tag thinking that it might help. But nothing changed.
3. Then I tried adding an image. function and it worked! But it worked the first time I loaded the screen only. Subsequent refreshes still had the required margin-top as 0: reverse output wrt earlier attempts. I also tried body.onload with a similar result.

Now I am stuck with no solution to this problem. I am trying to solve this all in pure javascript as I am new to js and know lesser about jquery. Simply, I want the image.clientHeight to display its correct value (pure js if possible). Please educate me on why this is not happening and help me further if you can. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest your code in an [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) instance.

Common mistake. It might be helpful to take some time researching how elements load on a page and some elementary HTTP concepts if you want to fully take advantage of JavaScript.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your suggestion. I tried using window.onload but since there are several images on my webpage; it takes a lot of time to make it readable as some text is hidden behind the image whose height defines the margin-top for the text. I was hoping to find a solution where the js can be run once this particular image is loaded. the other elements on the page can take their time to load. I will continue reading as you have suggested but if you can help me with this issue, it will be just great!

Comment: After reading a bit more, I tried body.onload again and certainly, window.onload seems to be faster. But still, I wanted it to be faster. Am I expecting too much?

Comment: @JayGadekar maybe I don't understand your question. You are loading images dynamically and want the page spacing to be setup so when the images load, the page doesn't shift upon load?

Comment: I was able to solve the issue using a timeout function to first find out the image height before the image is rendered. This way I don't need to use onload because it works only after the images are rendered. Thank you for your help.

var beforeImageRender = setInterval(function () {
  if (mainImage.naturalWidth) {
    clearInterval(beforeImageRender);
    //code here//
}, 0);